# BigQuery BigQueryParameter and parameterize where fields

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

What is the correct way to parameterize the field name in the `Where` statement?

My app dynamically creates `Where` based on the user's input.  Therefore I want to parameterize not only the values but the fields. When I do no results are given.  I want to be clear, not an error just 0 rows returned.

```
List<BigQueryParameter> parameters = new List<BigQueryParameter>()
parameters.Add(new BigQueryParameter("MyValue", BigQueryDbType.String, value));
parameters.Add(new BigQueryParameter(fieldName, BigQueryDbType.String, fieldName));
var sqlCmd = $"Select * from myProject.myDataset.myTable where @{fieldName} = @MyValue";
var queryResults = await _client.ExecuteQueryAsync(sqlCmd, parameters);
```

If I remove the `@` in front of `fieldName` the query works and returns the desired data;

```
List<BigQueryParameter> parameters = new List<BigQueryParameter>()
parameters.Add(new BigQueryParameter("MyValue", BigQueryDbType.String, value));
parameters.Add(new BigQueryParameter(fieldName, BigQueryDbType.String, fieldName));
var sqlCmd = $"Select * from myProject.myDataset.myTable where {fieldName} = @MyValue";
var queryResults = await _client.ExecuteQueryAsync(sqlCmd, parameters);
```

edit: add a bit more code for readability

Comment: Remember, you're not _parameterizing_ the field name, you using _string interpolation_ to compute the command. At least in standard SQL you can't parametrize a column name without resorting to dynamic sql.

Comment: @gunr2171 I am a bit confused by your comment.  I did a quick edit of the code.  I am making a list of BigQueryParameter, a string of the SQL command.  Then passing those to the BigQueryClient.   Sure I am using interpolation to create the SQL command but the parameter should be processed by BigQueryClient.  If you mean something, please explain

Comment: My comment deals with your second code block. If you remove the second `parameters.Add(...` line, you should notice that your code still works. That's because the name of the column itself is not a parameter - only `@MyValue` is. When it comes to using column names (select, where, etc) you can't use a variable/parameter _within the sql command itself_. That's why dynamic sql exists (and you should avoid it when possible) - so that you can use string concatination within the sql engine to create and execute the final command. In your case, just let c# do the string combining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column names, table names, or other parts of the query.

Read it here - [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries)
[C# Example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#c)